# WebSocket and Endpoint

Tags: java, websocket

My IDE : NetBeans, GlassFish.
I  am trying to understand how GlassFish execute and run the Endpoint!
I understand Glassfish as a webserver creates new Endpoint instance for each connection, and the Set : peers in the code appears as one global variable for every instance of endpoint.
My question is : how to add another global variable(s) so every instance of endpoint can access it?

```
 enter code here

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Set; 
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;



@ServerEndpoint("/echo") 
public class EchoServer {
    /**
     * @OnOpen allows us to intercept the creation of a new session.
     * The session class allows us to send data to the user.
     * In the method onOpen, we'll let the user know that the handshake was 
     * successful.
     */
     private static final Set<Session > peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session >());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){


        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
        try {
            peers.add(session);

            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException{

        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);

        for (Session  peer : peers) {
             peer.aplayer.getBasicRemote().sendText(" Message from " + session.getId()+" : "+message); 
        }
    }`enter code here`


    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
        peers.remove(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding another static field to your EchoServer class?

Comment: yes I did, it appears as a local variable, for example : int x; each instance of endpoint has its own value for x

Comment: STATIC (lower case) is the keyword you are looking for - that is shared among all instances. But you need to make sure you are using it correctly, especially when you accessing/setting it from multiple threads.

Comment: Yes Pavel, it works : public static int x=0;. Thanks :)

Comment: inside the event onMessage, I want to create a class, say Person(), the the Set peers would not recognized by the class Person unless I pass it as a parameter to the Person constructor. Is there an approach to keep a track  of global variables, a common place which any class(unit) can access. Something similar to ServletContext for the entire web app ?

Comment: In another words, I need to implement an object and run  only one instance of it before the container create any instance of endpoint, and all the variables inside that object can be seen by all endpoint instances.